# How to insert backslash(\) into MySql DB?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Hi i am working with Swings File Chooser... One Click of Button, File chooser will open and i select the Jar which is inside `C:\A\B\selenium.jar` and when i print in net beans with print statement it prints as `C:\A\B\selenium.jar`(good) but when i try to insert the same string in to My Sql Workbench DB it is inserting as `C: AB selenium.jar` ...

From this path i need to convert it to a File using `new File(.../Path)` which i require in later use... But i am getting `java.io.File Not Found Exception: C : JARS selenium.jar` (The system cannot find the file specified)

please help me....

Answer (score 1):

Use escape sequence `\\`.

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ("my \\backslashed values.");
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Comment: Hi i tried with your approach using INSERT into jars (ProjectId,JarName,JarPath) values('7','bshclient','\\C:\apache-jmeter-2.6\lib'); but it is inserting as \C:apache-jmeter-2.6lib but i want it in this way C:\apache-jmeter-2.6\lib...

Comment: Try "C:\\apache-jmeter-2.6\\lib"

Comment: Backslashed doesn't means adding "\\" to the beginning of the string. It means each occurrence of "\" must be preceded with another "\", like "\\".

Comment: Thanks, adding the two backslashes for each backward slash did the trick for me